# JavaScript timer function not working in IE10 while it does work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am currently stuck on a `JavaScript` code piece which **DOES** work in `chrome (version 44.0.2403.125)` but **DOESN'T** in `IE 10`.

I've read multiple issues on stackoverflow with (kinda) the same problem but all what is suggested there doesn't seem to work for me (or I don't implement it correctly).

Anyway I am stuck on the following:
I've got a timer function in `JavaScript` which does a countdown from 10 minutes to 0, when reaching 0 minutes it fires a `jquery` function, a popup box.

The javascript code is as follow:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                my_fun(); //the jquery function that popups the message-box 
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000); //how fast to count
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    };
</SCRIPT>
```

The Jquery function is pretty long (to paste here) but this doesn't seem to be the problem. I used the jquery function separately (without firing it from JavaScript) and this works in IE - it popups when its called in the html. Besides that I referenced the `jquery-1.11.2.min.js library` which overcomes pretty much all browser incompatibility problems (as far as I know).

The next thing I checked for was the IE10 Console log. There I noticed that it kept generating the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference.
```

This made me believe that the `textContent` property is unavailable in `IE10` so I checked that as well, though after research I found out this property is allowed (should work) in `IE10`.

The next thing I could think of was that the `window.onload` was not working in IE10, I read a few suggestions about using **new** in the `onload` in IE10 like this: `window.onload = new function` but this also didn't had any effect.

Then I try'd to paste the `window.onload` JavaScript code above the timer function so that perhaps the textContent isn't empty but this also didn't have any effect.

So now I am out of ideas, anyone has a clue how I can fix it?

**UPDATE**

Thank you all for the answers and suggestions! After trying all the suggestions it still took a while to get it fixed but nonetheless I got it fixed.

First I try'd to add the `var display;` as a global but this didn't had any effect. So next I looked at my code page in general.
I am working on a asp classic page and doing a lot of server side stuff. The page view depends on some queries. But that aside, I had my `$time ID` after some asp classic server side handles so I thought that moving the ID up tot the page (before the server side stuff) could make it work. But this didn't had any effect. I tried several things after that and honestly I can't remember all of it.

Then I saw #Arunachalam answer and thought this could actually work since my other JQuery did its job in IE while JavaScript didn't. So instead of using:

```
window.onload = function () {
            var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
                display = document.querySelector('#time');
            startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
        };
```

I used the JQuery version of it:

```
$(function() {

 var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,display = document.querySelector('#time');  
 startTimer(tenMinutes, display);

}
```

But sadly this also didn't had any effect.. 
100 tries/adjustments later (and reversing them since they didn't work) I tried it again with Jquery but modifying it to:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
});
```

and combining the `JavaScript` function and the above `Jquery` function in the same SCRIPT tag by changing  `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` to `<SCRIPT>`

And that did the trick! Got it working now!

Comment: I know, I just didn't changed the text of it to tenminutes (yet)

Comment: [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/drbjpn5r/)??? Notice, that your error message says that `#time` is not defined. Are you creating `#time` dynamically in `$(document).ready(...)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using JQuery, I recommend you to call your function inside JQuery onload instead of Window onload.

```
$(function() {

 var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,display = document.querySelector('#time');  
 startTimer(tenMinutes, display);

}
```

Comment: Got it working! You pointed me in the right direction but your initial code needed some adjustment. Check out my update in the main post!

Answer (score 3):

Add `var display;` before the line `function startTimer(duration, display) {...`

The error means that the variable `display` is not found within the scope you were using it. Defining it at the top will make it a global variable which will then be accessible anything within the code.

Complete code should look like this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    var display;
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                my_fun(); //the jquery function that popups the message-box 
                timer = duration;
            }
        }, 1000); //how fast to count
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        var tenMinutes = 60 * 10,
            display = document.querySelector('#time');
        startTimer(tenMinutes, display);
    };
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: @R3tep Yes but it is being called at `startTimer(tenMinutes, display);`, and right before that, the variable `display` has not been defined using the keyword `var` at anytime. So two possibilities, either the element with id _time_ is not found (less likely) or IE is throwing error because the variable has not been defined (most probable) :)

Comment: Tend to agree with the fact that `time` cannot be found in IE.

Comment: How could `display` not be defined within `startTimer`? It's in the argument list, hence it always exists.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your point. "before being passed as parameter ... when was it defined?", it was defined just one line before ...

Comment: @Teemu,  I believe, window onload called before elements are loaded. So, querySelector('#time') returns null, because of this null is assigned to display variable and passed as argument. If we are using JQuery, it is better to use JQuery onload which handles both IE and Chrome in a better way irrespective browser speed.

Comment: @Arunachalam I agree, that's why I've upvoted your answer : ), though it's risky to answer a question, where the issue is not re-produceable.

Comment: There is no value in declaring as variable and also passing as argument. Obviously, in function argument value will be evaluated.

Comment: @Teemu Got it working using JQuery (but a bit modified) as suggested! Check out the update on the main post.

Answer (score 0):

The timer works perfectly. `display` refers to `null` in IE. Your code is good. I guess `time` isn't present somehow in IE.